# urllib:-HTTP Error 404: Not Found while importing excel file through URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

below is the my code, here m not able to read the excel file.
i'am getting error like HTTP Error 404: Not Found. please help me out in this.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file is just not there. Check if your url is valid.

Also, this is not a Python related question.